# Cannot install SQLITE3 with JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, jruby

I am brand new to Ruby and using Windows 7. It is a different environment to what I am normally used to so I am having problems getting a simple project going.

After reading several tutorials, it appears that JRuby is the simplest way to go on windows which I have done. I am now trying to create a web application from scratch but I am confused about this shell style method of working.

I have downloaded sqliste3.def, sqlite3.dll and sqlite3 which I have put in the:
    C:jruby-1.6.4>bin
directory. However, I am now trying to install sqlite but with no avail. Firstly what I would like to know is which console environment does one use to do this. Is this cmd or the IRB console?

Whenever I use cmd the default line is c:\users\me> and I don't know if this is affecting how things should work.

Whenever I try to install SQLITE3 I am assuming that i need to go :

```
c:\users\me>gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

However I am not getting anywhere and receiving the following error:

```
WARNING:JRuby does not support native extensions or the 'mkmf' library very well
```

I have heard a lot of good things about Ruby and I am simply trying to build a basic webpage with a contact form but I seem to be running into all sorts of issues with the project installation and simply getting ruby up and running. Are there any tutorials that explain how to start a web project with JRuby and Sqlite3 from scratch?

Answer (score 6):

As the warning suggests, `sqlite3-ruby` requires native C extension, and it does not work well with JRuby.

You should use `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter` instead.

https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter

See https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

Comment: Thanks for the reply Banzaiman but I am still having problems. I have installed the adapter by putting it inside the bin directory then      (c:\users\me>jruby -S gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter) and it gives me the 1 gem installed response. But then when I proceed with trying to install sqlite3 as above it fails in the same way again. Am I doing something wrong? COming from a Windows background I am not familiar with this way of installing files so perhaps I am not putting them in the correct places or using cmd properly.

Comment: Did you try `activerecord-jdbcsqite3-adapter`? It turns out that what you want is `jdbc-sqlite3` gem, which is a dependency of the JDBC adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed this now but I am still confused as to what is the point of Jruby if I can now go and create user> rails new testapp. All the files have been created but How do I know it is working? I have tried jruby/server but no avail..Apologies for this but I am finding all this cmd way of installing things very obscure, I thought that the whole point of installing jRuby is to have a set up environment

Comment: That's too big a question to really answer. See https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki or Using JRuby (http://pragprog.com/book/jruby/using-jruby)