# gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundle, sqlite3-ruby

when i try to install the sqlite3 with this - > `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'`

this errors appears:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    /home/arthur/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/bin/jruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby >or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.
>
> (root) at /home/arthur/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
>    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
>     (root) at /home/arthur/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
>     (root) at extconf.rb:3
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 >for inspection.
>   Results logged to /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install SQLITE3 with JRuby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754100/cannot-install-sqlite3-with-jruby)