# An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

So im trying to `$ bundle install --without production` before I `$ git push heroku master`but i keep getting this error

```
$ bundle install --without production
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies......
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.5
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.99
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.1.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.8
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 3.1.4
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.4
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.1.8
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass-rails 4.0.5
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151208-25620-qipdd0.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:3

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

this is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'



group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I tried to

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
gem install sqlite
```

But i got

```
$ gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151208-19428-iytd2g.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:3

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
```

Does any one have any ideas to what could be causing this?

Comment: Which OS you are using ?

Comment: here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795942/how-to-enable-c-extension-support-in-jruby

Comment: You're trying to use the native sqlite gem with Jruby. This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7786796/163640

Comment: Windows for Ruby on Rails! I hope god will always be with you :)

Answer (score 31):

I think you need to install sqlite3 and sqlite3-dev first.

```
sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Have a try, might solve your problem

Comment: thank's a lot. It still works on Ubuntu 18.04 and rails 6.0.

Answer (score 7):

This might help. I have the same problem. I searched a lot and I solved it. This is maybe just about sqlite3's version.

You should do this first

```
sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

then open your Gemfile and change the line of sqlite3 to

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'` This part did not work for me but this one `sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As benjamin said, you need to install the sqlite3 database before you can install the sqlite3 gem. It looks like you are on Windows, so try following the instructions listed here:

[How do I install sqlite3 for Ruby on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows)

For reference, here is the accepted answer on that thread, by user Williams:

1. Install the Ruby Devkit for your setup (DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe for me since I use a x64 machine)
2. Download and extract the autoconf package from Sqlite.org
3. Run msys.bat (it is inside the ruby devkit root folder)
4. cd into the path where you downloaded the sqlite source (for example: "cd /c/dev/sqlite3" for path "c:\dev\sqlite3" if you are new to MSYS/MINGW32)
5. Run "./configure"
6. Run "make"
7. Run "make install"
8. Get the sqlite3 gem again, this time specifying the platform and the path to the newly compiled binaries:

   `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=[path\to\sqlite3.h] --with-sqlite3-lib=[path\to\sqlite3.o]`

   For example:

   `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=/c:/dev/sqlite3/ --with-sqlite3-lib=/c:/dev/sqlite3/.libs/`

   (from the paths given in step 4)
9. Check the Gemfile.lock of your rails app and make sure that it points to the correct sqlite3 version. Mine was "sqlite3 (1.3.7-x86-mingw32)" and manually changed it to "sqlite3 (1.3.7-x64-mingw32)". Removing the platform also works: "sqlite3 (1.3.7)".

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This will install the sqlite-related packages required by Rails on **RedHat** and **Centos**:

```
sudo yum install sqlite sqlite-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the *sqlite3* database for your operating system, preferably through the tool your OS provides. After doing this, try installing the gem again. Chances are you have to resolve similar errors by the same procedure.

Comment: I posted above the results i got from $ gem install sqlite3 . The i posted above is the error im having installing sqlite3.

Comment: In case the link in Joel's answer is outdated, just google for installation+sqlite3+your_os_version. Installing other gems can fails with similar error messages, so repeat the procedure if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```