# cannot load such file — sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

2.5.1 Ruby, 5.2.1 Rails versions. Everything is installed from scratch. Im trying to create a project in RubyMine, and this error pops up right from the start, and i can do nothing untill this error is solved.
This solution didnt work for me:
[cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)
Couldnt make to the end of this solution:
[An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171874/an-error-occurred-while-installing-sqlite3-1-3-11-and-bundler-cannot-continue)
on 5-th step after execution of "configure" promt says that no acceptable c compiler found in PATH.
Help please.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there are some problems with compability on this versions of ruby, rails, and sqlite. I've installed rails installer with 2.3.3 ruby and 5.1.6 rails, and error dissapeared.